# Multiple Conditions in Table Rate Shipping (2.x)

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I haven't set up any table rate shipping in **Magento** before so this may be a very simple question with an obvious answer. Is there a way baked into default **Magento 2.x** to specify shipping based on multiple conditions. For example:

All items under 300 lbs are $15 **flat rate** for all of those items but every item over 300 lbs is $55 for each item.

I know it's likely to require a custom shipping method but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

First go to `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options and lbs as weight unit`. 
Then go to `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Change Store view to Main website -> Enable Table Rate and Import your tablerate.csv` file with following content as in the image. 
[image]

Comment: This is how I have it right now however the shipping cost becomes $55 total rather than $55 per item as I need it. That is my challenge as I need flat-rate up to 300lbs and per-item shipping after 300.